# React crossorigin in Script tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Why is the keyword crossorigin used while including React Scripts ?
and
What happens if we dont use it ?

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can use the following <script> element to tell a browser to execute the https://example.com/example-framework.js script without sending user-credentials. - [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes)

Comment: Note: it seems that the property is now camel-cased `crossOrigin`, accepting a *string*. Such as `crossOrigin="anonymous"` or `crossOrigin="use-credentials"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> crossorigin
>  Normal script elements pass minimal information to the
>   window.onerror for scripts which do not pass the standard CORS checks.
>   To allow error logging for sites which use a separate domain for
>   static media, use this attribute. See CORS settings attributes for a
>   more descriptive explanation of the valid arguments.

— [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)